# Alternative to Spinner? ( other ways to choose from a list?)

Tags: java, android, spinner

I want my users to choose something in one of my screen but i'm tired of the spinner. Can anyone suggest how can i add a cooler way to choose stuff?

Comment: Try ListView or Custom Dialog.

Comment: You might be tired but your users will thank you for using recognisable, consistent interface elements.

Answer (score 0):

If  you're tired of a spinner, why not create your own styled dialog to select things.   You can make it look however you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have too many options and/or they are labeled with short texts, you can consider using [`RadioGroup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html) with radio buttons. This would of course go either directly on your activity (taking more space than a spinner) or inside a custom dialog.